# Define a sequence by two conditions and show this sequence converges and find its limit

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence

**Question:** Define a sequence $(a_n)$ by two conditions $(a_1) = \sqrt{2}$ and $(a_n+1)= \sqrt {2+(a_n)}$ for $n \ge 1$. Show that this sequence converges and find its limit. (Suggestion: Show that the sequence is monotone and bounded)

**Given:** $(a_n)$ is defined by two conditions

**My proof**

Write out a few terms according to the condition provided:
$(a_1) = \sqrt {2}$, 
$(a_2) = \sqrt {2+ \sqrt {2}}$, 
$(a_3)= \sqrt {2+ \sqrt {2+ \sqrt {2}}}$, 
$(a_n$) = \sqrt {2+ (a_{n-1})}$, 
$(a_{n+1}) = \sqrt {2+(a_n)}$

From the sequence that I write out, we can see that this is a non-decreasing sequence, because we keep adding a number to the previous term. 
Also, we know that $(a_1$)\leq(a_n)\leq(a_{n+1})$
Thus, the sequence $(a_n)$ is a monotone sequence and it is bounded.

According to a theorem, we know that every bounded monotone sequence is convergent.
So $(a_n)$ is convergent, so the limit of this sequence exist and the limit for $(a_n)$ is $L$

$(a_n) \leq (a_{n+1})$
$(a_n) \leq \sqrt {2+(a_n)}$
Square both sides and use $L$ (the limit of $(a_n))$ to replace $(a_n)$, 
we obtain
${L^2}-L-2 leq 0$
Apply the quadratic formula, we got $L \leq 2$.

Therefore, the limit for $(a_n)$ is $2$.

I am not sure if it is ok to conclude this sequence is monotone and bounded by just writing out the first couple of terms. Any suggestions and helps are super appreciated.

Let me know if the format is not readable.

Thanks 
JY

Comment: Proof of monotonicity and boundedness is needed.  It is for example easy to prove by induction that $a_n$ is less than $100$.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion!

Comment: You are welcome. Monotonicity also has a straightforward induction proof, from $a_k\lt a_{k+1}$ you can deduce $a_{k+1}\lt a_{k+2}$.

Comment: One you know the limit exists, you should not use inequality, you should use $L=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n+1}=\sqrt{2+\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n}$. Then we get a quadratic *equation* for $L$.

Comment: Yes, that is what I am doing right now! Thanks for your suggestion!